# My indents for my loops look strange, is this normal? (python 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, while-loop, indentation

I'm trying to create loops when certain conditions are met and so far it works but when I try to create more conditions I have to indent them even more in order to get my program to work.

```
def terrain(surface):
    surface = raw_input("What surface will you be driving on? ")
    while surface != "ice" and surface != "concrete" and surface != "soil" and surface != "asphalt" :
        surface = raw_input("Surface not valid. Please enter a valid surface: ")
    if surface == "ice":
                u = raw_input("what is the velocity of the car in meters per second? ")
                u = int(u)
                while int(u) < 0:
                    u = raw_input("Velocity must be a positive integer: ")
                                while int(u) == 0:
                                    u = raw_input("Velocty must be a number greater than zero: ")
                        while int(u) > 72:
                                                                u = raw_input("This vehicle cannot reach this speed: ")
                a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
                a = int(a)
                while int(a) > 0:
                    a = raw_input("Deceleration cannot be a positive integer: ")
                else: 
                        s1 = u**2
                        s2 = 2*.08*9.8
                    s = s1/s2
                    print "This is how far the vehicle will travel on ice: "
                    print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
terrain("ice")
```

I just want to be able to create more loops without the wild indents

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `without the wild indents`? If you need to use a loop or a `if` statement you must compulsarily use indention. Its a language requirement.

Comment: Python relies on indents to understand what code belongs to what statement/loop/function/class. As for line 12 and 13, they can be shifted back one indent and line 15 can be shifted back 9 indents.

Comment: `while surface != "ice" and surface!=....` is confusing. Consider using `valid_surface = ['ice', 'concrete' ...<other valid option>]` and then `while surface not in valid_surface: <do stuff>`.
I believe the else block should be indented only once

Comment: @SuvenPandey What I mean is that when I want to create another loop for my program I have to create an even more indented line under the already indented loop, as you can see above for the while loop. I wanted to create a third loop for the 'u' variable right below the previous one and it keeps giving me an indention error no matter how far I shift the line.

Comment: @pythonstudent23 Is this the exact code you are trying with all indents exactly same as above?

Comment: @SuvenPandey yes

Comment: Can you please include pseudocode in your question of what you are trying? like if (surface is ice) {get value for u, if (u < 0) display error message} else {do this}

Comment: @SuvenPandey I never wrote in pseudocode before but I just want to add a line that works like what you put. a loop that works like: if(surface is ice) {enter value for u} and then {enter value for a}. while (a < -55) prompt user to try again

Comment: @pythonstudent23 I asked for pseudocode because your code has me seriously confused. You have `else`block below `while a > 0` by that `else` do you mean `if surface is not ice` or `if a is not > 0`

Comment: I suggest you to use a proper IDE (such as the free version of PyCharm) instead of using a text editor, especially if you are new to Python. It will indent properly for you.

Comment: @SuvenPandey the else is for when the user inputs pass the conditions. "if the user inputs agree with these conditions do this, or else do this"

Comment: Check the answer I posted below, and see if it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I understand comment if I am wrong:
1. get value for surface
2. if (surface is invalid) ask for another value
3. if (surface is ice):
  a. get value for u
  b. get value for a
  c. calculate s using formula
   `s1 = u**2`
   `s2 = 2*.08*9.8`
   `s = s1/s2`
  d. display s 
4. If surface is not ice do nothing(as per code you posted but it can be edited to have similar blocks like `if surface == "soil"` )
If so then

```
def terrain():
    surface = raw_input("What surface will you be driving on? ")
    valid_surface = ["ice", "concrete", "soil", "asphalt"]
    while surface not in valid_surface:
        surface = raw_input("Surface not valid. Please enter a valid surface: ")
    if surface == "ice":
        u = raw_input("what is the velocity of the car in meters per second?")
        while int(u) < 0:
            u = raw_input("Velocity must be a positive integer: ")
        while int(u) == 0:
            u = raw_input("Velocty must be a number greater than zero: ")
        while int(u) > 72:
            u = raw_input("This vehicle cannot reach this speed: ")
        a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
        a = int(a)
        while int(a) > 0:
            a = raw_input("Deceleration cannot be a positive integer: ")
        while int(a) < -55: #note all while blocks are at same level
            #Do stuff  #contents inside while is indented by 4 spaces
            a = raw_input("This vehicle cannot have this deceleration. Please input another value: ")

        s1 = u**2
        s2 = 2*.08*9.8
        s = s1/s2
        print "This is how far the vehicle will travel on ice: "
        print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
```

I usually define a function like:

```
def get_int(prompt, error):
    variable = input(prompt)
    while True:
        try:
            variable = int(variable) 
        except ValueError:
            variable = input(error)
            continue
        break
    return variable
```

and use it as:

```
v1 = get_int("Enter value for accn: ", "Please input integer: ")
v2 = get_int("Enter value for velocity: ", "Please input integer: ")
```

You may need to change certain things such as change `variable = int(variable)` to `variable = float(variable)` if you need to accept floating(such as 1.25) value.

Comment: When I run this code, the print statement "This vehicle cannot have this deceleration" runs as an infinite loop. I switched it to a raw_input and it fixed it. This code looks good but when I get to the "deceleration cannot be a positive integer" part it keeps on going no matter what.

Comment: @pythonstudent23 you will need to have another raw_input inside each while statement

Comment: Also note that giving non-int input(like apple) causes ValueError exception to be raised so you might want to handle that.

Comment: Yeah that's the part I fixed. But now the only issue I'm having is the fact that it keep repeating that part no matter what I type. Even if the deceleration value is acceptable.

Comment: I actually fixed it. I just switched out the 'a' with int(a) in the while statement.

Comment: how can I avoid that ValueError? Another condition, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code, I will point out some of them. Also you should start using python3.x instead of python2
You can directly parse the input you take from the user as `int(raw_input("xyz"))`
Keeping all of the above in mind, the code below should work

```
import sys

def terrain():
    surface = raw_input("What surface will you be driving on? ")
    vel = -1
    while surface != "ice" and surface != "concrete" and surface != "soil" and surface != "asphalt" :
        surface = raw_input("Surface not valid. Please enter a valid surface: ")
    if surface == "ice":
        vel = int(raw_input("what is the velocity of the car in meters per second? "))
    while vel < 0:
        vel = int(raw_input("Velocity must be a positive integer: "))
    while vel == 0:
        vel = int(raw_input("Velocty must be a number greater than zero: "))
    while vel > 72:
        vel = int(raw_input("This vehicle cannot reach this speed: "))
    acc = int(raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? "))
    while acc > 0:
        acc = int(raw_input("Deceleration cannot be a positive integer: "))

    s1 = vel**2
    s2 = 2*.08*9.8
    s = s1/s2
    print ("This is how far the vehicle will travel on ice: ")
    print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s))

terrain()
```

Read up on how indentations work in python, because they are the way to start new blocks of code, and try to add more conditions on top of the code I formatted for you, then you can understand it better.

Comment: I plan on combining my program with someone else's Tkinter module so I don't want the sys.exit() to end the entire program just because a condition is met. I also wanted the the error messages to loop, hence the while statements.

Comment: Updated. please check!

Answer (score 0):

1. Whenever you indent, you should always add the same amount of indentation. There's no need to use 4 spaces of indentation in one place and use 12 spaces someplace else. The most common convention is to use 4 spaces.
2. Only add an indent level when starting a new block, i.e., the line following a line that ends with a colon.
3. When ending a block, the following line must line up with the keyword that started that block. Of course, that can mean outdenting more than one level if more than one block ends at the same time.

This is what your code might look like without the indentation-related syntax errors:

```
def terrain(surface):
    surface = raw_input("What surface will you be driving on? ")
    while surface != "ice" and surface != "concrete" and surface != "soil" and surface != "asphalt" :
        surface = raw_input("Surface not valid. Please enter a valid surface: ")
    if surface == "ice":
        u = raw_input("what is the velocity of the car in meters per second? ")
        u = int(u)
        while int(u) < 0:
            u = raw_input("Velocity must be a positive integer: ")
            while int(u) == 0:
                u = raw_input("Velocty must be a number greater than zero: ")
            while int(u) > 72:
                u = raw_input("This vehicle cannot reach this speed: ")
        a = raw_input("How quickly is the vehicle decelerating? ")
        a = int(a)
        while int(a) > 0:
            a = raw_input("Deceleration cannot be a positive integer: ")
        else: 
            s1 = u**2
            s2 = 2*.08*9.8
            s = s1/s2
            print "This is how far the vehicle will travel on ice: "
            print ("The vehicle will travel %i meters before coming to a complete stop" % (s))
terrain("ice")
```